# Indexed image gallery

Tags: images, document-indexing, search, gallery

I've got a repository of (aprox.) 1000 subfolders containing over 400K+ jpeg files. Many users were searching there by the files' metadata using Adobe Bridge, but it has grown over for Bridge to be able to store metadata in its cache (That is per-user).

So a much better approach would be a central (web?) indexed gallery. I need to be able to add files from CLI also. Has anyone a detailed advice?
I'm currently testing about piwigo (after gallery devs closed the project), but I can't find a good way of either preseed the files or add them from a script.

Answer (score 2):

Try Zenphoto I believe you can upload using Command Line and big size file images.

Zenphoto is a CMS for selfhosted, gallery focused websites. Our focus lies on being easy to use and having all the features there when you need them (but out of the way if you do not).

Zenphoto features support for various media formats and integrated blog and custom pages. Zenphoto is the ideal CMS for personal websites of illustrators, artists, designers, photographers, film makers and musicians.

http://www.zenphoto.org/

Comment: I did try zenphoto (going for a second test round now), but I had problems with the initial preseeding. Zenphoto should be better as is directly filesystem based (as per docs), but the indexing/scanning of such a pool needs very large php memory and timeout limits.

Answer (score 2):

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is a search webapp that can handle huge volumes.

It is easy to install (just unzip and run `solr start`) but it can be tricky to configure to your exact needs/content, because there are so many options.

For EXIF data, see how to configure Solr (in conjunction with [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)) here: http://solr.pl/en/2012/02/20/simple-photo-search/

Usable from CLI.
A search GUI is available, but it is also very easy to integrate into your own portal:

[image: Solr search results]